# jquery prompt title is not displaying

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm writing a jquery prompt with an "OK" button, and I need to display the title as well, but apparently, except the title, rest (the content and the button) are displaying properly. Here is the code I have tried.

```
    jQuery.prompt('Sorry! This feature has been disabled. To enable this feature, click <a href="'+baseurl+'aa/bb">here</a>', {
            title: 'Manage Feature',
            buttons: { "Ok": true }
        });
```

If there's anything that I have done wrong in this code, please show me the error so that I can proceed the rest.

Thank you.

Comment: You could provide jsFiddle for that.

Comment: Is this jquery? http://jquery.com/?s=prompt - Not found

Comment: This works for me? I'm assuming you're using Impromptu though...which could be incorrect. http://jsfiddle.net/TajQz/

Comment: Hi, yeah!! am using impromptu. Why is it incorrect? and yeah, it's working fine in jsfiddle, but not working in my project, anyway, let's see. thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not use prompt use confirm here's a sample

```
jConfirm('Can you confirm this?', 'Confirmation Dialog', function(r) {
    jAlert('Confirmed: ' + r, 'Confirmation Results');
});
```

for more info [click here](http://labs.abeautifulsite.net/archived/jquery-alerts/demo/)